# Add GeoDataFrame Points to OSMnx graph and connect to closest node

Tags: python, networkx, geopandas, osmnx

I have a problem that I can't seem to connect my points (bronnen (*sources*)) from a gdf to a graph that I need for a shortest distance analysis. I want to check the shortest distance from my points to a node and then add my point to the graph a create an edge with the nearest node and my point.

So I have the following code:

```
place = ['Halle, Belgium', 'Beersel, Belgium']
graph = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='all')
edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph, nodes=False, edges=True)
nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph, nodes=True, edges=False)

graph = ox.projection.project_graph(graph, to_crs=31370)

bronnen = gpd.read_file('Bronnen.shp', crs=31370)

G = graph #graph

bronnen['x'] = bronnen.geometry.x
bronnen['y'] = bronnen.geometry.y
bronnen['coords'] = bronnen.geometry.apply(lambda p: list(p.coords)[0])

punten = bronnen.explode(column=None)
point_coords = punten['coords']

nearest_nodes = []

for coords in point_coords:
    x, y = coords
    point = Point(x, y)
    nearest_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, point.x, point.y)
    nearest_nodes.append(nearest_node)

for idx, coords in enumerate(point_coords):
    x, y = coords
    point = Point(x, y)
    G.add_node(idx, x=point.x, y=point.y, geometry=point)

for idx, nearest_node in enumerate(nearest_nodes):
    G.add_edge(idx, nearest_node)
```

The error message I always seems to get is:

```
msg = "scipy must be installed to search a projected graph"
raise ImportError(msg)
dist, pos = cKDTree(nodes).query(np.array([X, Y]).T, k=1)
nn = nodes.index[pos]
else:
if unprojected, use ball tree for haversine nearest-neighbor search

File _ckdtree.pyx:561, in scipy.spatial._ckdtree.cKDTree.__init__()

ValueError: data must be finite, check for nan or inf values
```

Especially looking at my gdf, you can see there are not really NaN of Inf values.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asuMg.png)

Thanks in advance!

Once it seemed to work, but then I tried to generalize the code to use for other point data. But then it was gone again.